# Calculating variance of $c=a/b$ based on $\sigma_a$ and $\sigma_b$ (error propagation)

Tags: correlation, variance, uncertainty, error-propagation

My  problem concerns the calculation of variances in 2 different ways (the variances calculated in the 2 different ways do not seem to match)...

I have the following data:

> For variable $A$: $\;\;\;\;$       2,  1, 2
>
> For variable $B$: $\;\;\;\;$       8,  3,  1

Now define variable $f$ as follows: $f:=A/B$, so:

> for variable $f$ this becomes:  $\;\;\;\;$ $\frac{1}{4}$,
>   $\frac{1}{3}$, 2

Now the variance of $f$ can be computed through 2 methods:

**Method 1**

$$var(f)= \frac{1}{3-1} \sum_{i=1}^3 (f_i - \bar f)^2,$$
where $\bar f$ is the average of the $f_i$'s (simple computation yields: $\bar f= \frac{31}{36} ) $

> This gives: $var(f)\approx 0.975$.

**Method 2**

Through propagation of uncertainty (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty)

For $f$ the following holds true (see above wiki link):
$$var(f)= \sigma_f^2 =f^2 \left( \left(\frac{\sigma_A}{A}\right)^2 +\left(\frac{\sigma_B}{B}\right)^2  - 2 \frac{\sigma_{AB}}{A\times B}  \right). $$
where $\sigma_{AB}$ is the covariance.

It is easy to calculate (using the sample variance formula) that: 
$\sigma_A^2 = \frac{1}{3}\approx 0.3333$ and $\sigma_B^2 =13$.

Furthermore (using Excel), $\sigma_{AB}=Cov(A,B)=\frac{1}{3}\approx 0.3333$.

Substituting $\sigma_{AB}$, $\sigma_{B}$, $\sigma_{B}$ and  $A=\bar A$, $B=\bar B$, $f=\bar f$ into the above formula for $var(f)$ yields:

> $var(f)\approx 0.617$

***My question is: why do I get 2 different numbers for the variance of $f$?***

Comment: you are confusing the variance of a random variable and the sample variance of observations from a random variable.

Comment: In the first case you made an error.  You got 31/36  for the mean by dividing by 3 when you your equation says to divide by 3-1=2. Also in using A and B you are pairing the three obs in A with the three in B to get the variable for the ratio.  Is that consistently done in both computations?

Comment: Answer by method 1 is 31/24 approximately equal to 1.29.

Comment: In method 2 if you use the sample variance formula for A as you claim you should get  0.4787/2 =0.2393 approximately.  This is not 1/3 even if you divide by 3.  The sample variance for B is 26/2 =13 as the OP get correctly.  If division by 3 you would get 26 /3=8.67 approximately.

Comment: You misunderstand Wikipedia by overlooking its repeated references to "approximation" and "estimation": Method 1 gives the variance whereas "propagation of uncertainty" (Method 2) is merely *approximate.*  At the end of a [recent post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/254962/919) I list the assumptions needed for the approximation to be reliable. In your case, taking the reciprocal $a/b$ is highly nonlinear in the range of values in your example, indicating the approximation is likely to be poor.  BTW, I suggest ignoring the comments by @Michael: he makes extensive arithmetical errors.

Comment: @whuber I was merely pointing out that the OP was computing the standard deviation for the samples using the formula that the OP used in Method 1 for Method 2. It is simple arithmatic..  You point out where you think I made errors!

Answer (score 3):

First, $Cov(A,B)=0.5$.

Second - you get different answers because you have calculated different things.

In first case you calculating variance of $f$ as if it is a random variable. So if we wish to write our $f$ like $Mean\pm Var$ we wold get $0.861\pm  0.975$.

In second case you know that $f$ is not random by itself but created from two random variables with their own errors. Our estimation of $f$ in not $Mean(A/B)$ but $Mean(A)/Mean(B)$ (beacause $E[f(A,B)]\approx E[A]/E[B]$ for [ratios](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~hseltman/files/ratio.pdf)). And using same notation as in first ($Mean\pm Var$) and [formula for variance of ratio](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~hseltman/files/ratio.pdf):
$$
Var(f)=Var(A/B)\approx\frac{E^2[A]}{E^2[B]}\left(\frac{Var(A)}{E^2[A]}+\frac{Var(B)}{E^2[B]} - 2\frac{Cov(A,B)}{E[A]E[B]}\right)
$$
 we get $f$ as $0.417\pm 0.136$. If we assume A and B to be independent, we can drop covariance term and get $Var(f) = 0.161$.

Comment: This answer seems to contribute to the confusion.  The OP is treating A and B as samples from two distributions in both cases.  The notation is confusing as is the definition of f.

Comment: There is probably nothing wrong with this answer using the assumptions you have made but  I think the OP was confused and was trying to compute sample estimates for both methods.  The OP made several errors and I was just pointing it out by showing what the OP should have gotten using the formula in Method 1.  I also demonstrated that using division by three other conflicting values arise. I think Bill Huber miunderstood what I was doing.