# What does gradient with respect to a function mean

Tags: calculus

I am trying to understand this paper better **[Greedy function approximation: A gradient boosting machine](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/trebst.pdf)**, but I start having difficulty at around Equation (6) and (7).

[image]

What does a gradient w.s.t. to an equation mean ($\partial F(x)$), could anyone provide a concrete example showing how it could be calculated?

Comment: It is to a partial derivative of a vector by another vector. It will come down to calculating a matrix where each element is a partial derivative w.r.t to each of the dimensions in vector x.

Comment: This stuff can get pretty heavy pretty quickly.  If you plan to continue your investigations or studies in this area, time spent with the introductory chapter of a good multivariate Calculus text will likely spare you grief and effort.

Comment: There must be thousands of examples of computing gradients on this site: search for [gradient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=gradient+-boosting+score%3A1).  Your specific question about what the gradient means is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96604.  I found a few more direct answers, too: see the links at the top of this page.